# Bootstrap Carousel issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am currently having an issue with my carousel. I mean it works fine but there are wierd symbols new the buttons to change slides.

[image: My issue]

I don't know how to fix this. Here is the code for it.

```
 <div class="well">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
      <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
      <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
      <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
</div><!--/item-->

<div class="item">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
</div><!--/item-->

<div class="item">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
        <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;" /></a></div>
    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
</div><!--/item-->

</div><!--/carousel-inner-->

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div><!--/myCarousel-->

</div><!--/well-->

<!-- This is just a little bit of custom CSS code to enhance things. Feel free to place this in your main CSS file. I've commented to say what each bit does. --> 
<style type="text/css">
/* Removes the default 20px margin and creates some padding space for the indicators and controls */
.carousel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
}
/* Reposition the controls slightly */
.carousel-control {
    left: -12px;
}
.carousel-control.right {
    right: -12px;
}
/* Changes the position of the indicators */
.carousel-indicators {
    right: 50%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: -19px;
}
/* Changes the colour of the indicators */
.carousel-indicators li {
    background: #c0c0c0;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
background: #333333;
}
</style>

<!-- Call jQuery 1.9, call bootstrap.js and run the carousel when the DOM is ready. Slide every 10 seconds. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
    })
});
</script>
```

Can you please help?
Thanks!

Comment: in chrome right click the weird symbol and figure out the source of it

Comment: try to post a demo link

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
```

your code probably looks like this. You need to delete the little arrows between your a tags.

Comment: <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Try to replace them with icons.